# Magento - link Configurable Product image to Simple Product image

Tags: magento

Magento 1.8

I have a configurable product with several simple products. These simple products need to have the same product image as the configurable product. As I don't want to upload to every simple product is there a way to link the product image of the configurable product to the simple products?

The reason is because I have an ajax product added popup which has a thumbnail which pulls images from simple product, also in the cart page.

I have tried inserting the following code in `app\design\frontend\<pachage>\<theme>\template\catalog\product\view\media.phtml after $_product = $this->getProduct();` after `$_product = $this->getProduct();`

`$_parentIdArray = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());if(sizeof($_parentIdArray)==1 && Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_parentIdArray[0])->getTypeId() == 'configurable'){
  $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_parentIdArray[0]);
}`

But it doesn't work. Anybody have idea on this?

[image: Simple product added missing image]

Answer (score 0):

This ajax product pop up is from which file . whats the file path, check the image path in that file.